# Is the image of a continuous map/operator closed

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading through Brezis Functional Analysis book. I am trying to understand why every closed subspace of finite codimension admits complement. The proof is as follows:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSHdi.png). It is assumed that $G \subset E$ and $E$ is a Banach space.

The Hahn Banach theorem that the proof refers to is the following: [Hahn Banach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fA7Y.png)

However, I do not understand how we can necessarily invoke the 2nd geometrical Hahn Banach theorem here (seperating hyperplane theorem), since in that case we would need to find a convex, compact set (this could be the point which is not included in the range of the linear map $\Phi$) and a closed, convex set. This "could" be the range of $\Phi$ since this is convex since any linear transformation of a convex set is convex - my question is then: is the range of a linear continuous map into a finite dimensional space always closed? I realise that the graph of any continuous function closed, but I do not believe the same holds for the range.

I guess one way of proving that the range is closed could be the following:

Pick sequence $\{\Phi (x_n)\}$ that converges to some element $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We wish to show that $y \in \text{Rng}(\Phi)$. But this holds since $\Phi$ is continuous so $y=\lim_{n \to \infty}\Phi (x_n)= \Phi (\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n)$ (here, we use the fact that the space $E$ is a Banach space and thus contains all its limit points).

But if this holds, then the range of any continuous map on a Banach space would be closed, which I do not believe is correct, which is why I am confused.

Comment: The range is a subspace, and every finite dimensional subspace is closed.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense.